# Give role to user in a server through DM discord

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, roles

I don't actually know much of programming nevertheless I am trying to make a discord bot that asks and takes answer from a user in their DM and assigns a specific role in the server.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const < role > = '<roleid>';
bot.login('<token>');

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    var mem = (message.author.id)

}
if (message.content == '<hotword>') //calls bot in the server verification channel
{

    message.reply('Hi there! Check your personal message if you want to become one!');
    message.author.send('<question>'); //dm's the user
    message.author.send('<hint>');
}
if (message.content == '<ans>') {
    message.reply('Congrats!! ');
    message.author.send('<next question>');
}
if (message.content == '<ans>') {

    message.author.send('Impressive! ');
    message.guilds.get('<ServerGuildID>').members.get(mem).roles.add( < role > ) //assigns role

}

});
```

I think there's something wrong in `message.guilds.get('<ServerGuildID>').members.get(mem).roles.add(<role>)` line but don't know enough programming to solve it.

Comment: `bot.guilds.get("GuildId").members.get(message.author.id).roles.add(role)`. I recommend you to switch to Discord JS V12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using **v12**? I hope so, it's different with some syntax to previous versions, which will be unsupported in october - so I recommend changing asap.

Anything with a **.get** must be replaced with a **.cache.get** - as seen in the [v11 to v12 updater guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html).

That'd make your code be `bot.guilds.cache.get(<ServerGuildID>).members.cache.get(<MemberID>).roles.add(<RoleID>)`

Comment: Thank you so much! i wasnt aware that this would be soo easy!

Comment: No problem! I always recommend checking documentation or that v11 to v12 updater guide.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a general tidy-up of your code and have changed the following line:

```js
message.guilds.get('<ServerGuildID>').members.get(mem).roles.add(<role>) //assigns role
// to
(await bot.guilds.cache.get('<ServerGuildID>').members.fetch(mem)).roles.add(<role>); // assigns role
```

If you are ever unsure on particular properties or methods, refer to the [Discord documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

## Modified Code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const <role> = '<roleid>';

bot.on('message', async (message) => {
  let mem = (message.author.id);

  if (message.content === '<hotword>') // calls bot in the server verification channel
  {
    message.reply('Hi there! Check your personal messages if you want to become one!');
    message.author.send('<question>'); // dm's the user
    message.author.send('<hint>'); 
  }
  else if (message.content === '<ans>')
  {
    message.reply('Congrats!');
    message.author.send('<next question>');
  }
  else if (message.content === '<ans>')
  {
    message.author.send('Impressive!');
    (await bot.guilds.cache.get('<ServerGuildID>').members.fetch(mem)).roles.add(<role>); // assigns role
  }
});

bot.login('<token>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! As i said, i don't know much of programming. i knew that the code only had flaw in that line but couldn't get my head around to solve it